# Android Listview highlighting

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a listview with selected item highlighting and can get the highlighting to remain during scrolling (thanks to SO)...

My problem/question is this:  when I select a row in the list, the highlight on the previously chosen row goes away as expected except in one instance:  if I scroll the highlighted row to the top of the list, but not completely off the list (for example, data that is wrapped in txt2 [see my code below]...part of the item is off the viewable list, part of the item remains in the viewable list), and then click on another row below, **BOTH** of the rows are now highlighted, which I do not want!

Am I doing something wrong or is this a result of the recycling that goes on during listview scrolling?

Any ideas/suggestions/explanation will be most appreciated.

This is the code I am using in my adapter's getView method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            TextView txt1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            TextView txt2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
            TextView txt3 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt3);
            TextView txt4 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt4);

            if (position == gv.currentListRecord)
            {


  txt1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.episode_list_font_color_selected));

  txt2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.episode_list_font_color_selected));

  txt3.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.episode_list_font_color_selected));

  txt4.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.episode_list_font_color_selected));
            }
            else
            {

  txt1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.genre_list_font_color));

  txt2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.genre_list_font_color));

  txt3.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.genre_list_font_color));

  txt4.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.genre_list_font_color));
           }
           return row;
       }
```

Comment: I suppose that's because of `final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);`. Why have you declared it final?

Comment: I was not sure whether I needed it or not so I left it.  I have tested without it and get the same results.

Comment: You should not leave anything if you are not sure you need it. Get rid of it and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Do you call `notifyDatasetChanged()` when you selected the new item?

Comment: I do not; I was under the impression I did not need to as the data is not actually changing.

Comment: @MiroMarkarian Using `final` at that position does not matter. "Get rid of it and see if you get any errors" - He won't.

Comment: @NiekHaarman In fact it does. You shouldn't use `final` if you don't need it absolutely. Specially in adapters where views are constantly being recycled and reused. In fact OP's problem sounds too much like what would be happening if a final variable is used in adapters.

Comment: @MiroMarkarian No, no. The scope of the `final View` here is limited to this method. The reference to the instance where the variable `row` points to cannot be changed in this method anymore, the instance itself *can* change. *Finality does not mean immutability*. [Please get your facts straight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)#Final_variables).

Comment: @NiekHaarman OK. But I don't see any reason as to why he needs to use final. So I recommended to remove it. Now, I don't see the rest of his code. He might have used that for a reason. That's why I said get rid of it and see if you get any errors. Also this is a comment not an answer.  So no need to criticize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do here, is telling your `ListView` that is should redraw the item `View`s, by retrieving them again using `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)`. That is where you change the selected state.

To achieve this, call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on your `ListAdapter`. This will cause `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)` to be called again for all items on screen.

Assuming your `super` method efficiently recycles the `convertView`s, performance should not be an issue.

Comment: Where do I make this call?  When setting up the adapter or somewhere within the getView()?

Comment: Directly after you change `gv.currentListRecord`.

Comment: I have done that but my adapter variable is not recognized; making the adapter variable global on the page, I then get a failure when I try to create the listview...

Comment: Got it! And solved my problem!  Thanks Niek...I set my global adapter instance to my local listview cursor adapter...this.adapter=adapter...and voila!!!